# Raspberry Pi dnsmasq performance

Tags: networking, performance

I want to block ads in my whole network with dnsmasq running on a Raspberry Pi, connected via Ethernet to the router. Is there any reason to take a RPi3? Or is a RPi2 also sufficient for that task?

Answer (score -1):

An RPi2 is sufficient if your internet connection speed is less than 100mb/s which it is likely to be.  If you have a faster internet connection speed then you would be better off with the latest model of RPi3 (model B+) which has an ethernet speed of about 300mb/s (gigabit port but speed is limited by USB 2 bus).

Having said that I would try to make the change on the router instead.  I have DD-WRT installed on my router although I would recommend OpenWRT instead but either support dnsmasq modifications or even have specific services to block ads.

Comment: Your answer implies that the raspberry pi will be used as some sort of router between the internet and the LAN ... but, `dnsmasq` has nothing to do with routing

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just want to intercept the dns queries using `dnsmasq`. My home internet would be 10gbit synchronous, so the RPi would be a massive performance impact.